# The reason why can't I use calldata as a data location for constructor parameter

Tags: solidity, memory, constructor, calldata

I know what is difference between memory and calldata.
But seeing that I ask this question I don't seem to understand deeply yet.

I ran into an error message as below, when I used 'calldata' as a data location for constructor input argument.

```
"Data location must be "storage" or "memory" for constructor parameter, but "calldata" was given."
```

But, in constructor, I just only read the value to allocate storage without any changes.

Like example below,

```
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

contract Example {
   address theFirst;
   
   constructor(address[] calldata _addressList) {
      theFirst = _addressList[0];
   }
}
```

Comment: bro the error is saying every thing ;
i think calldata is only for parameter's of function's with implementation ( with {}).

Answer (score 3):

It's because the constructor is a special kind of function and how it gets called.

The contract is written to chain followed immediately by the constructor parameter data. The constructor then reads the parameter values by looking them up at that offset.

So, constructor parameters specifically are not of type `calldata`.